# Array incrementing and i++ issues

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm trying to use `i++` to store certain parts of an array in a loop. But instead of incrementing by 1, I really need it to increment by 2.

For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PeerTutoring
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        String name, degree;
        String line;
        line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inputs");
        String[] userinput = line.split("\\s+");

        for(int i = 0; i < userinput.length; i++)
        {
            name = userinput[a];
            degree = userinput[b];
            a+=2;
            b+=2;
        }
    }

    public static String sort(String name)
    {
        String tutors = "Tutor List";
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String> ();
        names.add(userinput[0]);
        names.add(userinput[2]);
        names.add(userinput[4]);
        names.add(userinput[6]);
        names.add(userinput[8]);
        names.add(userinput[10]);
        names.add(userinput[12]);
        names.add(userinput[14]);
        names.add(userinput[16]);
        names.add(userinput[18]);
    }
}
```

I want `a` to start as 0 and `b` as 1, and then each time I would like it to increase by two. (Since the names are each one is seperated by a space) I think I'm going to have to incorporate something along the lines of `userinput[a + 1]`. But I just wanted to know if there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=0, i < linesize; i += 2)
```

As a side note, make sure to initialize your variables outside the loop if you are planning to use them after, or they will be lost.

```
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        String name, degree;

        for(i=0, i < linesize; i += 2)
        {
            int linesize = line.size();
            String line;
            line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter tutor name and 
            their highest earned degree.");
            String[] userinput = line.split("\\s+");
            name = userinput[a];
            degree = userinput[b];
            a++;
            b++;
        }
```

Comment: Ok it seems to be working however, my separate method sort, doesn't seem to be able to find userinputs. I thought by sending String name, it would be able to access them.

Comment: Please explain in detail what exactly you are trying to do as I am a little bit confused. When you are prompted for input, it should follow the syntax of "<Name> <degree>" and the space is what is used to separate the two. In the code you have up at the top, the sort method is never called. Also if you could select a best answer that would be helpful also.

Comment: My sort method really going to sort anything(I don't know why I called it that). It's just putting the Names(everyother userinput) from the array into a list which will be organized later.(I haven't done anything with the degrees yet) I haven't called anything yet I don't believe. Later I had planned on doing sort(name) and then the undetermined degree method.

Comment: Okay. Well just make sure when you're adding input to follow the correct format. split("\\s+") is splitting the line into two tokens by the space character.

Comment: Is the error that my sort method isn't finding the userinputs because I haven't done sort(name); or is another reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

`i++; i++;` (Which you can't use in the `for` loop construct since you need a single statement.)

`i += 2;`

`i = i + 2;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    String line;
    line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter tutor name and 
    their highest earned degree.");
    String[] userinput = line.split("\\s+");

    for(int i=0, i < userinput.length; ){
    String name = userinput[i++];
    String degree = userinput[i++];
```

...

```
}
```